# A phrasal verb that means to prepare/cook something casually

Tags: word-request, phrasal-verbs

There's a phrasal verb that I forgot again, I think it has similar meaning to "grab a bite"; if I got it right it means to prepare something casual, quick to eat, even kinda of like to *snap up*.

I remember vaguely there's an example sentence in Macmillan Dictionary that goes *He came without calling so I XX an omelette for him,* but I'm far from sure that this is the original sentence.
Can someone help?

Answer (score 5):

Whip [something] up, or whip up [something].

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/whip-sth-up

> He whipped up an omelette.

Comment: Thanks for this hint, I then searched its synonyms and found the one I been looking for—throw together, anyway thank you so much for dropping “whip up” here

Comment: Knock [something up] and knock up [something] [(Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/knock_up) may be only BrE.

Comment: Rustle, likewise.

Comment: I often _sling something together_ if I have not had time to plan a meal.

Comment: sling together and knock together may work but cooks will prefer whip up as it refers to cooking. (as in whipped cream). The others just sound like guys who can't cook. :)

Comment: 'Whip up' sounds a bit American to me (I'm British).

Comment: @Lambie do you have a source for the claim that 'whip up' refers to cooking? I thought the 'whip' in this phrase was just describing a fast motion, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @AnonFNV The term is whip **up** some food. To make some food fast.